# Java Arrays Assistance

Tags: java, eclipse

I have the following 2 array codes.

```
    int max = 100;
    int length = 50;
    String [] cars = new String[length];
    int [] nums = new int [max];
```

I have 2 questions.

What is the value of nums[6]?

And,

What is the value of nums[max] ?

Comment: Is there a reason you are not able to run your code and find out for yourself?

Comment: @CharlesCaldwell I dont have Java here at my house....

Comment: @JoshuaJoseph That's exactly what websites like [Ideone](https://ideone.com/) are for.  Just go type your code in there and click Run.

Comment: @azurefrog actually, Ideone is showing errors when I run it

Comment: @JoshuaJoseph that's because of the way that arrays are indexed in Java.  See M. Shaw's answer for more detail.

Comment: I have another question too.    Without using an initializer list, declare an array called theOtherNums and initialize its contents to 10, 20, 30, 40, 50.  How would I do this? @azurefrog

Comment: @JoshuaJoseph If you have another question you should open a new question to ask it.  Array initialization isn't really on the same topic as your original post.

Answer (score 1):

From the Java Language Spec:

```
 Each class variable, instance variable, or array component is initialized with a default value when it is created (§15.9, §15.10)
 For type int, the default value is zero, that is, 0.
```

So the answer to your first question is 0.

In Java, array indexes start with 0. Thus `array` has `array.length` elements with indexes `0, 1, 2, ... ,array.length - 1`, and `array[array.length]` would throw an `ArrayOutOfBoundsException`.

Answer (score 0):

nums[6] will be 0 because the int array would hold default values.

nums[max] will throw an exception, because your array's length equals max.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this answers your question.  nuns[6] is 0, because its the default value that java gives to arrays that haven't been specified.